# В Java какая разница / различия между суперклассами и интерфейсами?

Tags: java, интерфейс, extend

Класс, я так понимаю, может экстендить/наследовать ***суперкласс*** - это значит он похож на него по полям и методам.

Класс, насколько я понимаю, может имплементить/реализовывать ***интерфейс*** - это значит он будет похож на него по полям и методам.

На данный момент найдены следующие различия между суперклассами и интерфейсами:

ОТЛИЧИЕ 1: класс имеет право наследовать только от ОДНОГО суперкласса, а реализовывать интерфейс может от очень большого количества интерфейсов. Думаю есть еще отличия. (спасибо @NarasuOo)

ОТЛИЧИЕ 2: в суперклассе МОЖНО создавать объект, а в интерфейсе - нельзя.

Comment: под суперклассами вы понимаете абстрактные классы, тогда ответ зависит от версии джавы))

Comment: Хотя бы потому, что можно унаследовать только один класс, а реализация интерфейсов не ограничена. К тому же если для наследования необходима связь "является" между суперклассом и наследником, то для интерфейса это не нужно, поскольку он просто описывает поведение

Comment: @NarasuOo Если быть точным, то реализуемых интерфейсов не может быть больше 65535 штук

Comment: @NarasuOo, получается ОТЛИЧИЕ 1: класс имеет право наследовать только от ОДНОГО суперкласса, а реализовывать интерфейс может от очень большого количества интерфейсов. Думаю есть еще отличия. Кстати, я не совсем поняла про "просто описывает поведение". Возможно у тебя опечатка и поэтому не могу понять смысл предложения.

Comment: в интерфейсе можно создавать методы с реализацией по умолчанию

Comment: @DmitryShelemeh, я так понимаю, методы "по умолчанию" у интерфейсов - это такие методы которые не объязаны быть в классах котоые имплементнули/реализовали этот интерфейс. В связи с чем у меня вопрос - а в подклассах наследующих от суперкласса, мы объязательно должны создавать  все методы суперкласса? Вроде не объязаны. А значит в этом месте суперклассы и интерфейсы не отличаются а даже похожи. Нет?

Comment: @Marika ну грубо говоря да, в интерфейсе просто у метода есть default приставка, а в абстрактном классе нет приставки, просто реализовываем метод

Answer (score 0):

Различие между ними в том, что implements означает, что Вы используете элементы интерфейса в Вашем классе, а extends означает, что Вы создаете подкласс от класса, который расширяете (extend). В новом классе Вы можете расширить только один класс, но Вы можете реализовать столько интерфейсов, сколько захотите.
see also: http://mindhalls.ru/java-extends-implements-differences/

Comment: Вы говорите " implements означает, что Вы ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТЕ элементы интерфейса в Вашем классе, а extends означает, что Вы СОЗДАЕТЕ подкласс от класса". Это ж одно и то же. Класс не только ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТ интерфейс (его переменные и методы), но класс так же ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТ и суперкласс (его переменные и методы). Т.е. получается у суперкласса и у интерфейса ОДИНАКОВЫЕ функции. Ну и зачем тогда было их ОБОИХ создавать в Java - не понятно

Comment: смотри, интерфес - это представь как некий шаблон, который ты конкретно описываешь исходя из своих нужд (один и тот же интерфейс ты можешь по разному описывать/реализовывать) и ещё - ты ОБЯЗАНА описать все методы интерфейса!
а вот наследование это если ты хочешь какой-нибудь метод из другого класса у себя использовать (можно его также переписать под свои нужды @Override) 

я наверно понимаю, что тебя ставит в тупик - то что по сути одно может заменить другое. Но ньансы на практике всё расставят на свои места :)

PS омерзительно, что в комментариях не поддерживается формат текста!

Comment: UPD: почитайте Шилдта Java. Полное руководство. Глава 8.

Comment: несколько дней назад искала как тут форматировать коменты. не нашла. думала что это я такая неумёха - не могу найти инфу. а оказывается тут нет такой возможности)) очень рада что узнала это